# VueJS 2 conditional rendering in value binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I simply try to let VueJS 2 render a inline condition while I add a value to an dom element. I know, that it is possible to use `v-if` to let elements appear or disappear based on conditions, but how can I use a *inline-condition*?

I will give an example. The following html *describe my idea* **and I know that this lines generates an error**. Both `<span>` elements are controlled by  conditions which lets them appear or not and this works fine.

Now, I try to bind a value to the `href` attribute *depending* on a condition (which are in the parentheses for example).

```
<div id="vuemain">
<span v-if="diced < 6">Looser</span>
<span v-if="diced == 6">Winner</span>
<a :href="'https://link-to-whatever.com/'+{diced==6 : 'winner', diced<6 : 'looser'} ">LINK</a>
</div>
```

So after rendering by VueJS the `<a>` tag should be like:

```
<a href="https://link-to-whatever.com/winner"> <!-- If diced == 6 -->
```

OR

```
<a href="https://link-to-whatever.com/looser"> <!-- If diced < 6 -->
```

Do you understand what my problem is and is that somehow possible?

Many thanks in advance

Allan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
<a :href="'https://link-to-whatever.com/'+ (diced==6 ? 'winner' : 'looser')">LINK</a>
```

It looks like you were trying to use the object syntax, which won't really work in this case. Instead, just use the ternary above.